# Tracking a trigger from a dropped table

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have dropped a table which contains a trigger. Is it possible to view or track the trigger of the dropped table.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The trigger no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Once the `Table`is dropped, there is no way to view or get the `trigger`. I could not add as a comment so adding it as an answer.